# Input range slider as react hook does not slide

Tags: reactjs, slider, react-hooks

I am trying to make a basic input range slider component using React hooks.
However, sliding the actual value knob does not work.
Only clicking directly on a new value location on the slide track changes the value.

Example codepen:
https://codepen.io/rmichels/pen/WNegjyK

this is my current component code, which the above codepen reproduces:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const useSlider = (min, max, defaultState, label, id) => {
  const [state, setSlide] = useState(defaultState);
  const handleChange = e => {
    setSlide(e.target.value);
  };

  const Slider = () => (
    <input
      type="range"
      id={id}
      min={min}
      max={max}
      step={10}
      value={state}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );

  return [state, Slider, setSlide];
};

export default useSlider;
```

I want to click on the knob and slide it left and right, firing the `onChange` function and triggering `setState` on the value as it's changed.

Answer (score 5):

Your component is setting state on each update of the slider, so the component is re-rendering and you lose focus or hold of the slider handle. Instead, you should update state when the interaction with the handle is complete.

```
//import { useState } from 'react';
const { useState } = React;

const useSlider = (min, max, defaultState, label, id) => {
  const [state, setSlide] = useState(defaultState);
  const handleChange = e => {
    console.log('setting level', e.target.value)
    setSlide(e.target.value);
  };

  const Slider = () => (
    <input
      type="range"
      id={id}
      min={min}
      max={max}
      step={0.5}
      // value={state} // don't set value from state
      defaultValue={state} // but instead pass state value as default value
      onChange={e => console.log(e.target.value)} // don't set state on all change as react will re-render
      onMouseUp={handleChange} // only set state when handle is released
    />
  );
  return [state, Slider, setSlide];
};

const App = () => {
  const [slideValue, Slider] = useSlider(
    1,
    100,
    70,
    "Threshold",
    "threshold"
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <Slider />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Avoiding setting state does delay when the rerender occurs, but if the component renders for any other reason at all (say, some parent component sets state in the middle of the drag) then the issue will reappear.

Answer (score 3):

Every time this hook gets called you define a brand new Slider functional component. The first time App renders, you render a Slider version 1.0. The second time, you render a Slider version 2.0. They may have very similar code, but they're different components and so react unmounts the old component and mounts the new one. Thus, the old input is removed from the dom and a new one is put in its place, and you're no longer dragging anything.

Hooks are not good for dynamically creating components. You could improve this somewhat by memoizing the slider component, but as soon as you have to break the memoization for any reason, a brand new component will have to be defined and this issue or ones like it will reappear.

Instead, i would recommend that useSlider return the props, and then have the caller put them onto a standard `input` component. Since the component is always of the same type, it will no longer be unmounted and remounted.

```
const useSlider = (min, max, defaultState, label, id) => {
  const [state, setSlide] = useState(defaultState);
  const handleChange = e => {
    console.log('setting level', e.target.value)
    setSlide(e.target.value);
  }

  const props = { 
    type: 'range',
    id,
    min,
    max,
    step: 0.5,
    value: state,
    onChange: handleChange
  }
  return props
}

const App = () => {
  const sliderProps = useSlider(1, 100, 70, "Threshold", 'threshold');
  return (
    <div>
      <input {...sliderProps}/>
    </div>
  )
};
```